# UDP multicast packet caught by tcmp dump but not received by socket

Tags: sockets, udp, multicast, tcpdump

I'm doing research on bigdata. For that, I have developed a network with several nodes exchanging UDP unicast and multicast packets. There are UDP packets with 33792 bytes and Ack packets with 37 bytes. MTU is set to 1500. Everything works fine for a little, lets say 300 to 5000 packets exchanged. Then suddenly some machine receives the packet (I can see it with `tcmpdump -i any -vvv -XX -e -s 64 > dump.txt 2>&1`). But the application socket doesn't receive it (select doesn't wake up).

I'm using IPv4 sockets with TTL set to 1, i.e. Local network.

After nights trying to solve I end up setting:

```
sudo sysctl -w  net.core.wmem_max=134217728
sudo sysctl -w  net.core.rmem_max=134217728
sudo sysctl -w  net.ipv4.udp_mem=1638400 1638400 1638400
sudo sysctl -w  net.core.somaxconn=4096
sudo sysctl -w  net.core.netdev_max_backlog=262144
sudo sysctl -w  net.core.optmem_max=134217728
sudo sysctl -w  net.ipv4.udp_rmem_min=65535
sudo sysctl -w  net.ipv4.udp_wmem_min=65535
```

`The client sockets set SO_SNDBUF to 134217728 (128 M), and server socket sets SO_RCVBUF to same value.`

But looks like still haven't solved the problem. Any thoughts??? .... TIA

Comment: Eh? 'Caught by `tcpdump`' but 'can't see it with `tcpdump`', and 'received by socket' but 'socket desn't receive it'? Make up your mind.

Comment: Thanks for advising. I have edited the question.

Comment: Which OS are you using? What do you mean by "some machine receives the packet"? Is this a different machine that the one running the application with the application socket?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it seems it solved the problem. Anyone wanting to in details (advantages/disadvantages/tradeoffs) the sysctl values I set is very welcome tough.

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the multicast group to reliably receive multicast packets.

On UN*X this is done with something like

```
struct ip_mreq mreq;
setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mreq, sizeof(mreq));
```

The pitfall is that if something is not set up correctly (or does not work properly, e.g. a switch) you will be able to receive multicast traffic for some time, and then, out of a sudden, it stops. So when you receive packets you 'cannot' draw the conclusion "everything is ok".

Also: All the potentially transparent infrastructure in your network (e.g. level 2 switches == normal switches) need to support the IGMP version your OS is using.